# How to set drawable image in fragment list adaptor in android

Tags: android, list, android-fragments

I have one problem my program crash on set image-view by drawable resource id.
I have array of image name from drawable folder.
How can I set image-view in adaptor of fragment.

```
       Resources resources = activity.getResources();
      final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("my_icon", "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
        holder.image.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Log ID is

```
04-26 13:52:25.291: E/AndroidRuntime(9517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 13:52:25.291: E/AndroidRuntime(9517): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 13:52:25.291: E/AndroidRuntime(9517):     at com.example.card.list_adaptor.getView(list_adaptor.java:72)
 04-26 13:52:25.291: E/AndroidRuntime(9517): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
```

In which activity is getactivity(); from fragment.

Any help is appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: add the logcat so we can examine it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin log added

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding Integer array

```
Integer []link={R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon2};
  and  set holder
 holder.image.setImageResource(link[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

setImageResource is dangerous as the documentation is saying that it can cause ["latency hiccup"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)

Use either setBitmap or SetImageDrawable..

**sample:**

```
 holder.image.setImageResource(getResource().getDrawable(resourceId));
```

Comment: i am trying to set drawable image in list adaptor in fragment so i had to use imageresource.